# internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException( ^ Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'postcss'

Tags: css, node.js, npm, postcss, postcss-cli

**Scss Postcss issues**

Hi found an issue with the postcss compilation error whereby the devdepencies compute the prefix output of the perfix.css as below:

> internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
> internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
> ^Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'postcss' imported
> from C:....s\node_modules\postcss-cli\index.js
> at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:655:9)
> at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:696:18)
> at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:810:11)
> at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:86:40)
> at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:230:28)
> at ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:56:40)
> at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:55:36) {   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
> `-- prefix:css: postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0
> prefix:css script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
> There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really a question.

Comment: @marvin-buge welcome to SO, please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and if you have the answer to your question, don't publish into the question details, add the answer using the "Post your answer" button

Comment: @joseLora i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found a simple solution to the problem:

1. Just update your node js to the latest version.
2. Reinstall autoprefixer after updating your node js application `{npm install autoprefixer --save-dev}`
3. Reinstall your postcss `npm install postcss-cli --save-dev`
4. Okay you will be ready to compile your Scss code.
   Hopefully, you will not face any issues compiling your output.